# switch variable gets first instance in php

Tags: php, switch-statement

I want to store a certain value during a switch/case in PHP, but I don't see what is wrong with this code:

```
<?php
$weegfactor=67;
$lus=12;

    if($weegfactor<70):
        switch($lus){
        case(1 || 7):
        $verdeling="AAABCD";
        break;
        case(2 || 8):
        $verdeling="AAABBE";
        break;
        case(3 || 9):
        $verdeling="AAAABC";
        break;
        case(4 || 10):
        $verdeling="AABBBD";
        break;
        case(5 || 11):
        $verdeling="ABBBCC";
        break;
        case(6 || 12):
        $verdeling="AABCCC";
        break;
        }
    endif;  

echo "weegfactor ",$weegfactor . '</br>' ;
echo "lus : ",$lus . '</br>';
echo "verdeling ",$verdeling;

?>
```

The outcome of the above code is:
weegfactor 67
lus : 12
verdeling AAABCD

Which is not correct because $verdeling should be "AABCCC".
What is my mistake??

Comment: Hint: what does `var_dump(1 || 7)` show?

Comment: It shows nothing: it is meant to determine the value of $verdeling.

Comment: you shoud use && not || [see this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: I think you should make one case for every number 1-12. Twelve case: I thiink previous poster is on the right track @Barmar

Comment: @user3107597 Did you try it? I just did, it printed `bool(true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 || 7` evaluates to a boolean type. So your program is doing a boolean comparison of `$lus` and `(1 || 7)`.

You will need to use two separate case statements for each:

```
switch($lus){
    case(1):
    case(7):
        $verdeling="AAABCD";
        break;
    case(2):
    case(8):
        $verdeling="AAABBE";
        break;
    case(3):
    case(9):
        $verdeling="AAAABC";
        break;
    case(4):
    case(10):
        $verdeling="AABBBD";
        break;
    case(5):
    case(11):
        $verdeling="ABBBCC";
        break;
    case(6):
    case(12):
        $verdeling="AABCCC";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Other solutions also did the job, but I like this one because  it is for me the most clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `case (x || y)` you probably mean when it is `x` or `y`. In that case you should do this:

```
switch($lus) {
   case x:
   case y:
      // do stuff
      break;
}
```

What you have now is a check against `x || y`, which is always resolves to a "truish" value, just like your value `12` is "truish", making the switch take the first branch.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `1 || 7` is `TRUE`, because both `1` and `7` are truthy. So the first case is equivalent to:

```
case TRUE:
```

And in fact, all your cases are equivalent to `case TRUE:`.

So it's then testing `$lus == TRUE`.  When comparing any type to a boolean, the other type is first converted to boolean (see [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for the complete list of how loose comparisons of different types are done). Since `12` is truthy (any non-zero integer is truthy), this comparison succeeds.

If you want to test against multiple values, use multiple `case` statements:

```
case 1:
case 7:
    $verdeling="AAABCD";
    break;
```